# AWS VPC DNS Hostnames on or off

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-vpc

I'm starting to work with a non-default VPC that has DNS Hostnames set to off.
I need to turn this on so I can add an RDS instance into the VPC.
I know I can do this from the VPC console but my question is what are the implications of this change?
What is the possible effects of this on what is already working and could it cause elements to stop working?
Basically, this VPC is simple enough with 3 subnets, there are 3 EC2 instance webservers working, each with a set of elastic IP addresses assigned to them with different private IP addresses, as all machines are running a handful of different websites.

Any advice appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

the name resolution will be the main aspect to consider, if you need or plan use dns in your servers with de DNS Hostnames set to on every instance will have a amazon provided name, and you not need to do this by yourself, but if you need specific dns names to this instances you could turn the DNS Hostnames to off, and install you own DNS server